# Vue.js, Three.js, how to change CSS style element in animation loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, three.js

I'm trying to convert my Three.js project with Vue.js

I have a Three.js scene with a 3D model and HTML points of interest on this model.

These points must remain fixed to the model and remain facing the camera.

Here a part of my code to do that, it works fine :

```
<body>
        <div class="point point-1">
            <div class="point__label">1</div>
            <div class="point__text">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

```
setPointsOfInterest() {
    this.points = [
        {
            position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0.2),
            element: document.getElementsByClassName('point-1'),
        },
    ];
}

animate() {
    for (const point of this.points) {
        // Get 2D screen position
        const screenPosition = point.position.clone();
        screenPosition.project(this.camera);

        // Transform points
        const x = screenPosition.x * window.innerWidth * 0.5;
        const y = -screenPosition.y * window.innerHeight * 0.5;
        point.element.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)`;
    }
    
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
}
```

With Vue.js, the point's position doesn't change when I set it with THREE.Vector3, it's only use the CSS style, why ?

And how can I change my CSS element inside my animate loop like here ?

Answer (score 2):

Vue.js strongly recommends you don't manually select the DOM elements it builds because you'll run into conflicting commands very quickly. Additionally, it builds & destroys elements based on its own components lifecycle, so they may not exist by the time you try to select `"point-1"`.

With this in mind, you shouldn't be using `documents.getElementsByClassName()` to select and manipulate elements, instead you should try using Vue's own [Template Refs system.](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) Once established, you should be able to update its CSS position like this:

```
this.$refs.point1.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px)`;
```